# Create Meta boxes in wordpress not to show in custom fields

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I used the below code to create a metabox for the post in wordpress. But the issue is that these meta boxes are also seen in the custom fields. I donot want these meta boxes to show in custom fields. Is there any way to avoid not to show meta boxes in custom fields as there is no use of showing it in the custom fields

```
$meta_boxes_video = 
array(
"hotel name1" => array(
"name" => "hotel_name1",
"type" => "input",
"title" => "<strong>Hotel Name</strong> (Required)",
"description" => ""),
"price1" => array(
"name" => "price1",
"type" => "input",
"title" => "<strong>Price</strong>",
"description" => ""),
"hotel name2" => array(
"name" => "hotel_name2",
"type" => "input",
"title" => "<strong>Hotel Name</strong> (Required)",
"description" => ""),
"price2" => array(
"name" => "price2",
"type" => "input",
"title" => "<strong>Price</strong>",
"description" => ""),
"hotel name3" => array(
"name" => "hotel_name3",
"type" => "input",
"title" => "<strong>Hotel Name</strong> (Required)",
"description" => ""),
"price3" => array(
"name" => "price3",
"type" => "input",
"title" => "<strong>Price</strong>",
"description" => ""),
"hotel name4" => array(
"name" => "hotel_name4",
"type" => "input",
"title" => "<strong>Hotel Name</strong> (Required)",
"description" => ""),
"price4" => array(
"name" => "price4",
"type" => "input",
"title" => "<strong>Price</strong>",
"description" => ""),
"hotel name5" => array(
"name" => "hotel_name5",
"type" => "input",
"title" => "<strong>Hotel Name</strong> (Required)",
"description" => ""),
"price5" => array(
"name" => "price5",
"type" => "input",
"title" => "<strong>Price</strong>",
"description" => ""),
"hotel name6" => array(
"name" => "hotel_name6",
"type" => "input",
"title" => "<strong>Hotel Name</strong> (Required)",
"description" => ""),
"price6" => array(
"name" => "price6",
"type" => "input",
"title" => "<strong>Price</strong>",
"description" => ""),
"img_name1" => array(
"name" => "img_name1",
"type" => "input",
"title" => "<strong>Img1</strong> (Required)",
"description" => ""),
"img_name2" => array(
"name" => "img_name2",
"type" => "input",
"title" => "<strong>img2</strong> (Required)",
"description" => ""),
);


function display_video_meta_boxes() {
global $post, $meta_boxes_video;
    foreach($meta_boxes_video as $meta_box) {

        echo'<input type="hidden" name="'.$meta_box['name'].'_noncename" id="'.$meta_box['name'].'_noncename" value="'.wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ).'" />';

        echo'<h2>'.$meta_box['title'].'</h2>';

        if( $meta_box['type'] == "input" ) { 

            $meta_box_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $meta_box['name'].'_value', true);

            if($meta_box_value == "")
                $meta_box_value = $meta_box['std'];
            $meta_box_value = str_replace("\"","'",$meta_box_value);

            echo'<input type="text" name="'.$meta_box['name'].'_value" value="'.$meta_box_value.'" size="55" /><br />';

        } elseif( $meta_box['type'] == "textarea" ) { 

            $meta_box_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $meta_box['name'].'_value', true);

            if($meta_box_value == "")
                $meta_box_value = $meta_box['std'];
            $meta_box_value = str_replace("\"","'",$meta_box_value);

            echo'<textarea name="'.$meta_box['name'].'_value" value="'.$meta_box_value.'" style="width:100%" cols="20" rows="1">'.$meta_box_value.'</textarea><br />';

        } elseif( $meta_box['type'] == "button" ) { 

            $meta_box_value = "Add New Source";

            if($meta_box_value == "")
                $meta_box_value = $meta_box['std'];
            $meta_box_value = str_replace("\"","'",$meta_box_value);
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            function test()
            {
            alert("fgfg");
            var element = document.createElement("textarea");
            element.setAttribute("value", "Dfdsf");
            element.setAttribute("name", "sdfdf");
            var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
            foo.appendChild(element);
            }
            </script>';
            echo '<div id="foo">';
            echo'<input type="button" name="'.$meta_box['name'].'" value="'.$meta_box_value.'" onclick="test();"  /><br /></div>';

        }
        elseif ( $meta_box['type'] == "select" ) {

            echo'<select name="'.$meta_box['name'].'_value">';

            foreach ($meta_box['options'] as $option) {

                echo'<option';
                if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, $meta_box['name'].'_value', true) == $option ) { 
                    echo ' selected="selected"'; 
                } elseif ( $option == $meta_box['std'] ) { 
                    echo ' selected="selected"'; 
                } 
                echo'>'. $option .'</option>';

            }

            echo'</select>';

        } elseif ($meta_box['type'] == "info") {


            echo '<p><strong>Add your property images using the "Upload/Insert" button above the content textbox..</p>';
        }

        echo'<p><label for="'.$meta_box['name'].'_value">'.$meta_box['description'].'</label></p>';
    }

}

function create_video_meta_box() 
{
    if (function_exists('add_meta_box')) 
    {
        add_meta_box( 'ameta_boxes', 'Extra Information', 'display_video_meta_boxes', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
    }
}

function save_video_postdata( $post_id ) {
    global $post, $meta_boxes_video;  

    if( get_post_type() == 'post' ) {
    foreach($meta_boxes_video as $meta_box) {  

        // Verify  
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[$meta_box['name'].'_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {  
        return $post_id;  
        }  

        if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {  
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ))  
        return $post_id;  
        } else {  
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ))  
        return $post_id;  
        }  

        $data = stripslashes($_POST[$meta_box['name'].'_value']);  

        if(get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'].'_value') == "")  
        add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'].'_value', $data, true);  
        elseif($data != get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'].'_value', true))  
        update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'].'_value', $data);  
        elseif($data == "")  
        delete_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'].'_value', get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'].'_value', true));  
        }
    }

}


add_action('admin_menu', 'create_video_meta_box');
add_action('save_post', 'save_video_postdata');
```

Answer (score 1):

Prepending the name of the field with an underscore will hide it. So:

```
if(get_post_meta($post_id, '_'.$meta_box['name'].'_value') == "")  
    add_post_meta($post_id, '_'.$meta_box['name'].'_value', $data, true);  
elseif($data != get_post_meta($post_id, '_'.$meta_box['name'].'_value', true))  
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_'.$meta_box['name'].'_value', $data);  
elseif($data == "")  
    delete_post_meta($post_id, '_'.$meta_box['name'].'_value', get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'].'_value', true));
```

You may also want to clean up some of your code a little. When update_post_meta is called, it will add the field automatically if it doesn't exist, so your add_post_meta call is superfluous in this context. Consider condesing this to either this:

```
if($data && $data != get_post_meta($post_id, '_'.$meta_box['name'].'_value', true))  
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_'.$meta_box['name'].'_value', $data); //Runs if $data exists and is different
else
    delete_post_meta($post_id, '_'.$meta_box['name'].'_value', get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'].'_value', true));
```

Or this:

```
if($data)  
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_'.$meta_box['name'].'_value', $data); //Runs if $data exists
else
    delete_post_meta($post_id, '_'.$meta_box['name'].'_value', get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'].'_value', true));
```